# SOLR Sorting parent via grand-child doc field value

Tags: sorting, solr

I have the documents as parent-child relationship:
https://gist.github.com/shadow-fox/fb525a7efe66622230e61d6253b6cfa9

How to sort the parent (type_s:product)s based on the grandchildren (type_s:vendor) field value ?

```
parent = type_s: product
children = type_s: sku
grandchildren = type_s:storage type_s:vendor
```

```
<doc>
    <field name="id">10</field>
    <field name="type_s">product</field>
    <field name="BRAND_s">Nike</field>
    <!-- nesting skus in product -->
    <doc>
        <field name="id">11</field>
        <field name="type_s">sku</field>
        <field name="COLOR_s">Red</field>
        <field name="SIZE_s">XL</field>
        <!-- nesting locations into sku -->
        <doc>
            <field name="id">13</field>
            <field name="type_s">storage</field>
            <field name="STATE_s">CA</field>
            <field name="QTY_i">10</field>
        </doc>
        <doc>
            <field name="id">14</field>
            <field name="type_s">storage</field>
            <field name="STATE_s">NY</field>
            <field name="QTY_i">0</field>
        </doc>
        <doc>
            <field name="id">15</field>
            <field name="type_s">vendor</field>
            <field name="NAME_s">Bob</field>
            <field name="PRICE_i">20</field>
        </doc>
        <doc>
            <field name="id">16</field>
            <field name="type_s">vendor</field>
            <field name="NAME_s">Alice</field>
            <field name="PRICE_i">22</field>
        </doc>
    </doc>
    <doc>
        <field name="id">12</field>
        <field name="type_s">sku</field>
        <field name="COLOR_s">Blue</field>
        <field name="SIZE_s">XL</field>
        <!-- nesting locations into sku -->
        <doc>
            <field name="id">17</field>
            <field name="type_s">storage</field>
            <field name="STATE_s">CA</field>
            <field name="QTY_i">0</field>
        </doc>
        <doc>
            <field name="id">18</field>
            <field name="type_s">storage</field>
            <field name="STATE_s">NY</field>
            <field name="QTY_i">100</field>
        </doc>
        <doc>
            <field name="id">19</field>
            <field name="type_s">vendor</field>
            <field name="NAME_s">Bob</field>
            <field name="PRICE_i">25</field>
        </doc>
        <doc>
            <field name="id">20</field>
            <field name="type_s">vendor</field>
            <field name="NAME_s">Alice</field>
            <field name="PRICE_i">28</field>
        </doc>
    </doc>
    <!-- nesting vendors into product -->
</doc>
```

The query:

```
{!parent which=type_s:product}
+COLOR_s:Blue 
+{!parent which=type_s:sku v='+QTY_i:[10 TO *] +STATE_s:CA'}
```

The result:

```
[
  {
    "id": "21",
    "type_s": "product",
    "BRAND_s": "Nike",
    "_version_": 1726713699507372000
  },
  {
    "id": "32",
    "type_s": "product",
    "BRAND_s": "Puma",
    "_version_": 1726713699562946600
  }
]
```

I want the results to be sorted by the matched `type_s:sku document`'s `type_s:vendor AND NAME_s:Alice`'s `PRICE_i` field in descending.

I have tried:

```
{!parent which=type_s:product score=max v=’+type_s:sku +{!func}PRICE_i’} desc
```

```
{!parent which=type_s:product score=max v='{!parent which=type_s:sku v='type_s:vendor AND NAME_s:Alice'}+{!func}PRICE_i' asc
```

However it gives "error in sort".

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, Solr treats all child levels in a similar fashion.
Also I create a variable:

```
childq={!parent which=type_s:product score=max v='+type_s:(vendor) +{!func}QTY_i'}
```

And then sort the products on the basis of this `childq` using `sort=$childq desc`.

In cases of debug, you can also use this value in `fl`; this will show if it is giving you the correct value.

```
fl=*,$childq
```

```
"q":"{!parent which=type_s:product}\n+COLOR_s:Red \n+{!parent which=type_s:sku v='+QTY_i:[10 TO *] +STATE_s:CA'}",
  "fl":"*,$childq",
  "sort":"$childq desc",
  "_":"1646831710752",
  "childq":"{!parent which=type_s:product score=max v='+type_s:(vendor) +{!func}QTY_i'}"}},
```